# Atempting to allow cgo to build on both Linux and Windows, get "build constraints exclude all Go files"

Tags: go, cgo

I am working on a smallish Go application that uses Cgo.  I'm working on it on a Linux VM, and Linux is the main target environment.  However, I have a need to also create a Windows executable.  Normally, cross-compiling Go is trivial, but Cgo adds some complications.  I've noticed at least two issues, but I'll only ask about the first problem here.

My application only has a single source file that requires Cgo, and the only difference between the Windows and Linux build is the lib path.

This is what I have so far for the beginning of the Cgo header.  After this are some include file references:

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall -I${SRCDIR}/../include/v6.21.0
#cgo linux LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/../lib/linux/v6.21.0 -lvibesimple -lcurl -lssl -lvibecrypto -lvibeictk -lvibeserver
#cgo windows LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/../lib/windows/v6.21.0 -lvibesimple -lcurl -lssl -lvibecrypto -lvibeictk -lvibeserver
```

When I build this on Linux, or with GOOS=linux, it works fine.

When I build this for Windows, I get this:

```
$ GOOS=windows go build -o target/dist/windows-amd64
package voltagems
    imports voltagems/app
    imports voltagems/handlers
    imports voltagems/voltagefuncs: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/<uid>/git/voltagego/voltagefuncs
```

I know that I can create files ending in "_linux.go" or "_windows.go", but that would be painful. That would mean duplicating the entire source file, and having to maintain both copies.

Comment: Did you set `CGO_ENABLED=1`? (unrelated to the build constraints error, you also may need to specify the C cross compiler)

Comment: Right. I forgot about that. Yeah, then I have to specify the CC value. Now I'm at the point of the second problem I have to solve. At least now the first issues are codified in my Makefile now.  I have to figure out where to get the "ssl" and "curl" libraries from.

Comment: For now, this has become moot. I discovered that I don't even need those libraries. I have other issues with the cross-compile link, but I might post on that tomorrow.